# How to export "circle" connections from Google Plus

Tags: contacts, export, google-plus

Is it possible to export one's "circle" connections from Google Plus?

For example, I have a circle of interesting people I'm following and would like to send the list to a friend.  How do I do that?

Comment: For what it's worth, it is now possible to "Share" a Circle to other people in Google+.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
2. Go to [Control your content](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy#takeout) (in the "Personal info & Privacy" section)
3. Click [Create archive](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) (of the "Download or transfer your content" section)
4. Click **Select None** (at the top of the list of all Google products)
5. Select the Contacts option, turning the checkbox there green
6. Click **Next**
7. Click **Create Archive** on the next screen

Some magic will happen and then you'll be prompted to download the generated archive.

The file will be in .vcf (vCard) format and contain both your Google Plus Circles and Google Contacts data.

Comment: Excellent, detailed answer.  And quick!

Comment: https://plus.google.com/settings/exportdata give a 404 error. Can you re-work your answer to work with [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout)?

Answer (score 0):

Go further and save them to your yahoo also. The best method for syncing is plaxo - as you have collected all your vcards and etc - it will allow you to upload from files from multiple sources so long as you use the .csv format or vcard